# Rails 5.2 Creating new belongs_to item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

Okay so I'm trying to create a new "belongs_to" item from its "has_many" Class.

In this case the class is Campaign and it "has_many" donations and the Donation class "belongs_to" :campaign.

```
def create
    campaign = @campaign
    @donation = campaign.donations.create(donation_params)
    # @donation = Donation.new(donation_params)
    if @donation.save
      return render html: SUCCESS_MESSAGE
    else
      return render html: FAIL_MESSAGE
  end
end
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
undefined method `donations' for nil:NilClass
```

Here are the classes:

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :donations
end

class Donation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

Also of note: I'm trying to do this from the Campaign "show" page.

Comment: looks to me that `@campaign` is undefined. The association looks correct. How is `@campaign` initialized in the controller?

Comment: Well I tried a couple of things like @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id]) but I get the error: "Couldn't find Campaign without an ID".

Comment: Please check the route and params again. I guess the params has campaign_id.
`@campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])`

Comment: you have to follow the trail that debugging takes you... "couldn't find Campaign without an ID" says that params[:id] is nil. Why is this? How is the id field supposed to be populated? I'm speculating that it should be in the url, which should probably look like '/campaigns/5/donations'. So is the form submitting to the correct url?

Comment: Ok this makes sense. The way it works is you're on the campaign page (so '/campaigns/7') and then you want to donate to that campaign "7". I'm not sure what the route should be after that... if that's what you're saying the problem is "match 'campaigns/:id/donation' => 'donations#create', via: [:get, :post]" Something like that?

Comment: @NeK  I already tried "campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id]) and got the same error"

Comment: Can you copy&paste the route for that action here in the routes.rb and also result from `rake routes`?